# Good example Chapel code for bad memory management?

Tags: chapel

Is there some good example code to show poor memory management (e.g. the programmer assumes there is garbage collection)?

I would like to demonstrate this during class.  The VM we're using has 16 available hardware threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent work in Chapel has been trying to reduce the number of cases where a programmer might unwittingly leak memory (for example, see the section on *delete-free programming* in the [release notes for Chapel 1.18](https://chapel-lang.org/releaseNotes/1.18/01-language.pdf)).  That said, allocating instances of `unmanaged` classes is a way to generate an intentional memory leak:

```
// run with --memTrack in order for the memoryUsed() call to work
use Memory;

class C {
  var A: [1..1000000] real;
}

for i in 1..1000000 {
  var myC = new unmanaged C();
  writeln(memoryUsed());
}
```

Specifically, the compiler is not responsible for freeing instances of unmanaged classes; the user must do so via the `delete` statement.  Failure to do so will cause the memory for that class to be leaked.

Therefore, a leak-free version of the above would be:

```
// run with --memTrack in order for the memoryUsed() call to work
use Memory;

class C {
  var A: [1..1000000] real;
}

for i in 1..1000000 {
  var myC = new unmanaged C();
  writeln(memoryUsed());
  delete myC;
}
```